# button.PerformClick() causing text to clear

Tags: java, android

I have an activity where a user sends messages to another user, I created an onKey listener to send messages when a user pressed enter as well.

When a user actually clicks the send button, everything works perfectly, when a user presses the enter button a blank message is sent.

Here is the onkeylistener code
**Code:**

```
        messageText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == 66) {
                sendMessageButton.performClick();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    });
```

and this is the sendmessagebutton
**Code:**

```
        sendMessageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        CharSequence message;
        Handler handler = new Handler();

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // android.text.format.DateFormat df = new
            // android.text.format.DateFormat();
            message = messageText.getText();
            String messageSent = DateFormat.format("dd MMM yy, kk:mm",
                    new java.util.Date()).toString();// java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss");

            if (message.length() > 0) {

                appendToMessageHistory(imService.getUsername(),
                        message.toString(), messageSent);
                ((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView))
                        .fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
                localstoragehandler.insert(imService.getUsername(),
                        friend.userName, message.toString(), messageSent);

                messageText.setText("");
                Thread thread = new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            if (imService.sendMessage(
                                    imService.getUsername(),
                                    friend.userName, message.toString()) == null) {

                                handler.post(new Runnable() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {

                                        Toast.makeText(
                                                getApplicationContext(),
                                                R.string.message_cannot_be_sent,
                                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                        // showDialog(MESSAGE_CANNOT_BE_SENT);
                                    }

                                });
                            }
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    R.string.message_cannot_be_sent,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };
                thread.start();

            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

When user clicks button

```
message = messageText.getText();// get message
```

Then you do

```
messageText.setText("");
```

So when user presses the enter button in `onKey` you have `sendMessageButton.performClick()` a blank message is sent since you already set `messageText.setText("")`

Comment: This is wrong. Since message = messageText.getText(), so message holds the text now, AND is used to send the message, not messageText, see: if (imService.sendMessage(imService.getUsername(),friend.userName, **message**.toString()) == null)

Comment: @Melquiades when you click the button again what happens then? that is what op has `sendMessageButton.performClick()` again `message = messageText.getText()` but messageText is `""`

Comment: I commented the `messageText.setText("");` part out, and it worked but the textview `messageText` stay filled with previous message. Somehow I am missing something, Why would that cause the issue? The kecode 66 should act the same as the button being pressed? What am I missing?

Comment: @ShaunJansenVanNieuwenhuizen when you send message you need to clear `messageText` and enter new value in `messageText` when you invoke `sendMessageButton.performClick()` this `message = messageText.getText()`. So you need to make sure message gets new values. Do you enter new values?

Comment: @Raghunandan What happens is this following: A user enters a message into a `messageText` and clicks the `Send button` it send a the message to the other user, the `messageText` gets cleared. BUT when the same user enters text into `messageText` and intead of using the apps `sendButton` he then presses androids keyboard `Enter/Done` the same happens but the message sent is blank. Hope this makes sense?

Comment: @Raghunandan Also, it seems though that when pressing the button on the keyboard it act's like it was pressed twice, but the button itself only once. Not sure if that could be related?

Comment: @Raghunandan Before OP posted more comments here, I assumed that pressing button and pressing enter key were two separate events, and from the code it looked that there should be no issues, hence your answer made no sense. As OP explained in more details, your comments here and what is actually happening now makes MY comment wrong ;) For this reason, even though your answer is still not correct, I have retracted my downvote, and I apologise for the downvote.

Comment: This fixed it for me, changing this-> `keyCode == 66` TO THIS `keyCode == 66 && event.getAction()!=KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN`

Comment: @Melquiades i din't post what needs to be corrected i pointed out the mistake. And what is wrong with the answer?